# Vb.net serial Port Write

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I want to write into port.write a constant and a buffer in the same line?

Example output: send 00A4000C02

is there a solution ?

```
Dim sendcommand as String ="send"
Dim abyBufferEnvio() as Byte

 Try
         
            If sppuerto.IsOpen Then
                sppuerto.Write(sendcommand)
                sppuerto.Write(abyBufferEnvio, 0, abyBufferEnvio.Length)
                
                lResultado = 0
            Else
                lResultado = -1
            End If
```

Comment: The overload that takes a `String` simply calls `Encoding.GetBytes` and then calls the overload that takes a `Byte` array. You can do that yourself, calling `GetBytes`, combining the two `Byte` arrays and then passing the result to a single call to `Write`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon ...it means that in a example code:  ```If sppuerto.IsOpen Then
                sppuerto.Encoding.GetBytes(sendcommand)
                sppuerto.Write(abyBufferEnvio, 0, abyBufferEnvio.Length)```